# Bluetooth HC-05 Serial data delay, buffer problem?

Tags: serialization, bluetooth, serial-port, android-bluetooth, hc-05

I am attempting to send via Bluetooth two variables, separated by a comma, I have the HC-05 module, an FTDI USB to Serial converter, connected through a RS232 to TTL converter.

note that I am able to modify AT commands and stream data, however, the data corrupts every few seconds, which causes some data loss, and a non-smooth visualization.

Note that the first variable is just a growing number, every cycle, the second variable is a randomized value between 1500 and 1600

sending data every 100ms, I get the following result:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2022.03.09 21:31:51 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
     1.0,  1501.0
     2.0,  1536.4
     3.0,  1542.4
     4.0,  1591.9
     5.0,  1531.1
     6.0,  1551.8
     7.0,  1530.6
     8.0,  1582.5
     9.0,  1551.9
    10.0,  1563.7
    11.0,  1548.5
    12.0,  1576.4
    13.0,  1589.5
    14.0,  1597.5
                                   35.0,  1517.3
    36.0,  1569.0
    37.0,  1520.9
    38.0,  1542.5
    39.0,  1541.9
    40.0,  1564.7
    41.0,  1561.9
    42.0,  1572.9
    43.0,  1587.9
    44.0,  1542.9
    45.0,  1512.4
    46.0,  1522.6
    47.0,  1578.2
    48.0,  1584.4
    49.0,  1544.5
    50.0,  1516.9
    51.0,  1511.9
    52.0,  1538.8
    53.0,  1519.7
    54.0,  1525.6
    55.0,  1552.4
    56.0,  1554.0
    57.0,  1508.2
    58.0,  1557.0
    59.0,  1552.8
    60.0,  1566.4
 65.0,  1571.4
                          81.0,  1572.3
    82.0,  1555.3
    83.0,  1595.0
    84.0,  1505.6
    85.0,  1566.8
    86.0,  1527.6
    87.0,  1577.9
    88.0,  1530.7
    89.0,  1503.0
    90.0,  1572.1
    91.0,  1517.5
    92.0,  1520.1
    93.0,  1519.9
    94.0,  1506.5
    95.0,  1584.8
    96.0,  1542.5
    97.0,  1546.3
    98.0,  1567.2
    99.0,  1586.2
   100.0,  1551.9
   101.0,  1554.2
   102.0,  1537.6
   103.0,  1560.6
   104.0,  1570.7
   105.0,  1518.8
   106.0,  1552.7
                            127.0,  1571.8
   128.0,  1552.4
   129.0,  1573.7
   130.0,  1585.8
   131.0,  1515.8
   132.0,  1556.2
   133.0,  1549.7
   134.0,  1569.1
   135.0,  1571.1
   136.0,  1570.9
   137.0,  1523.4
   138.0,  1545.4
   139.0,  1595.1
   140.0,  1558.6
   141.0,  1547.4
   142.0,  1552.5
   143.0,  1595.7
   144.0,  1576.2
   145.0,  1509.0
   146.0,  1503.4
   147.0,  1530.5
   148.0,  1590.9
   149.0,  1518.9
   150.0,  1560.3
   151.0,  1505.9
   152.0,  1538.0
   157.0,  1596.4
   158.0,  1581.1
                        17   1   173.0,  1547.8
   174.0,  1567.8
   175.0,  1574.8
   176.0,  1522.9
   177.0,  1511.8
   178.0,  1563.4
   179.0,  1554.9
   180.0,  1515.1
   181.0,  1595.2
   182.0,  1581.4
   183.0,  1590.3
   184.0,  1523.9
   185.0,  1573.7
   186.0,  1582.7
   187.0,  1505.2
   188.0,  1582.1
   189.0,  1537.9
   190.0,  1544.3
   191.0,  1522.4
   192.0,  1546.4
   193.0,  1583.8
   194.0,  1587.7
   195.0,  1506.4
   196.0,  1512.5
   197.0,  1575.4
   198.0,  1518.4
                               219.0,  1509.1
   220.0,  1516.1
   221.0,  1586.2
   222.0,  1502.6
   223.0,  1522.2
   224.0,  1527.0
   225.0,  1552.6
   226.0,  1589.2
   227.0,  1594.6
   228.0,  1529.5
   229.0,  1511.8
   230.0,  1595.6
   231.0,  1512.9
   232.0,  1526.5
   233.0,  1526.8
   234.0,  1547.0
   235.0,  1503.6
   236.0,  1502.6
   237.0,  1507.4
   238.0,  1533.1
   239.0,  1511.0
   240.0,  1570.7
   241.0,  1540.6
   242.0,  1539.9
   243.0,  1557.3
   244.0,  1547.5
   249.0,  1509.4
  250.0,  1502.2
        25   2                   265.0,  1548.6
   266.0,  1555.8
   267.0,  1538.6
   268.0,  1553.4
   269.0,  1516.5
   270.0,  1556.7
   271.0,  1525.7
   272.0,  1508.9
   273.0,  1572.5
   274.0,  1508.1
   275.0,  1591.3
   276.0,  1522.7
   277.0,  1594.6
   278.0,  1528.2
   279.0,  1509.0
   280.0,  1505.7
   281.0,  1574.6
   282.0,  1535.6
   283.0,  1587.8
   284.0,  1526.7
   285.0,  1536.6
   286.0,  1562.5
   287.0,  1543.4
   288.0,  1560.5
   289.0,  1528.3
   290.0,  1547.6
   295.0,  1552.6
   296.0,  1576.1
         30                      311.0,  1586.9
   312.0,  1556.8
   313.0,  1515.4
   314.0,  1572.1
   315.0,  1590.3
   316.0,  1553.1
   317.0,  1528.2
   318.0,  1532.8
   319.0,  1526.0
   320.0,  1514.9
   321.0,  1534.7
   322.0,  1594.0
   323.0,  1522.6
   324.0,  1546.7
   325.0,  1519.5
   326.0,  1552.5
   327.0,  1571.8
   328.0,  1505.7
   329.0,  1532.4
   330.0,  1537.7
   331.0,  1539.3
   332.0,  1531.9
   333.0,  1575.1
   334.0,  1583.2
   335.0,  1575.4
   336.0,  1501.2
   341.0,  1519.9
   342.0,  1512.8
                         357.0,  1529.8
   358.0,  1538.9
   359.0,  1544.1
   360.0,  1593.0
   361.0,  1579.8
   362.0,  1564.4
   363.0,  1573.1
   364.0,  1582.0
   365.0,  1556.3
   366.0,  1505.0
   367.0,  1545.5
   368.0,  1570.6
   369.0,  1575.0
   370.0,  1530.0
   371.0,  1599.0
   372.0,  1527.5
   373.0,  1545.4
   374.0,  1535.3
   375.0,  1521.9
   376.0,  1526.5
   377.0,  1547.6
   378.0,  1531.1
   379.0,  1524.6
   380.0,  1542.8
   381.0,  1554.4
   382.0,  1558.4
   387.0,  1551.1
   388.0,  1598.5
                         403.0,  1512.0
   404.0,  1590.2
   405.0,  1539.8
   406.0,  1515.9
   407.0,  1587.6
   408.0,  1581.4
   409.0,  1507.8
   410.0,  1540.1
   411.0,  1554.3
   412.0,  1527.8
   413.0,  1567.8
   414.0,  1583.9
   415.0,  1575.6
   416.0,  1515.1
   417.0,  1536.0
   418.0,  1578.1
   419.0,  1596.2
   420.0,  1559.3
   421.0,  1539.6
   422.0,  1530.2
   423.0,  1567.2
   424.0,  1533.1
   425.0,  1556.7
   426.0,  1591.2
   427.0,  1593.1
   428.0,  1572.8
   433.0,  1559.5
   434.0,  1548.6
                       449.0,  1501.5
   450.0,  1524.1
   451.0,  1536.7
   452.0,  1576.1
   453.0,  1504.8
   454.0,  1575.6
   455.0,  1551.6
```

Then, attempting to plot data every 1ms, I get the following result:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2022.03.09 21:34:09 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
0,  1583.3
   445.0,  1506.9
   446.0,   446.0,  1578.9
   447.0.0,  1503.8
   461.0,  1570.2
   462.0,  1526.3
   463.0,  1.6
   477.0,  1503.3
   478.0,  1538.9
   479.0,  1569.2
   480.0,  1548.1
   481.0,  1538.7
   482.0,  1540.6
   483.506.0,  1559.6
   507.0,  1537.8
   508.0,  1582.2
   509.00,  1519.5
   523.0,  1589.5
   524.0,   524.0,  1563.2
   52,  1545.7
   541.0,  1558.2
   542.0,  1556.8
   543.0,  15  558.0,  1566.7
   559.0,  1503.1
   560.0,  1566.4
   561.0,  1550.6
   575.0,  1525.2
   576.0,   576.0,  1507.2
   577.0,  1564.5
   578.0,  1582.7
   579.0.0,  1547.6
  1477.0,  153,  1486.0,  1501.9
  1487.0,  1537.5
  1488.0,  1537.2
  1489.0,564.4
  1504.0,  1508.5
  1505.0,  1519.3
  1506.0,  1552.1
  1522.0,  1583.3
  1523.0,  1551.8
  1524.0,  1562.9
  1525.01538.0,  1581.6
  1539.0,  1530.8
  1540.0,  1522.6
  1541.0,  1553.2
  1542.0,  11561.0,  1508.1
  1562.0,  1562.9
  1563.0,  1562.6
  1564.0,  1564.0,  1594.5
  15658.6
  1584.0,  1516.9
  1585.0,  1526.6
  1586.0,  1534.5
  1587.0,  1550.1
  1588.04.0,  1526.8
  1605.0,  1570.5
  1606.0,  1550.9
  1607.0,  1543.1
  1623.0,  1574.3
  1624.0,  1556.7
  1625.0,  1530.8
  1626.0,  1504.0
  1627.0,  1529.3
  1646.0,  1582.7
  1647.0,  1572.2
  1648.0,  1503  1663.0,  1595.6
  1664.0,  1522.9
  1665.0,  1593.8
  1666.00,  1550.9
  1680.0,  1584.6
  1681.0,  1681.0,  1508.8
  1682.0,  1525.6
  1683.0,  1558.5
  168  1552.6
  1706.0,  1596.5
  1707.0,  1707.0,  1590.3
  17081.0,  1508.7
  1722.0,  1558.9
  1723.0,  1542.4
  1724.0,  1525.9
  1725.0,  1502.0
  1726.0,  1544.8
  1727.0,  1583.4
567.9
  1753.0,  1572.9
  1754.0,  1583.6
  1755.0,  1597.3
  1756.0,  1525.9
  1757.0,  1530.4
  1758.0,  1567.1
  1759.0, 1785.0,  1589.3
  1786.0,  1569.0
  1787.0,  1524.9
  1788.0,  1529.0
  1789.0,  1500.5
  1790.0,  1540.1
  1791.0,  1.0,  1507.3
  2736.0,  1505.0
  2737.0,  1571.5
  2738.0,  1539.6
  2739.0,  1515.6
  2740.0,  151.0,  1564.6
  2762.0,  1561.2
  2763.0,  1565.5
  2764.0,  15585.5
  2778.0,  1528.6
  2779.0,  1513.9
  2780.0,  1579.2
  2781.0,  1588.0
  2782.0,  1527.4
3.3
  2804.0,  1574.8
  2805.0,  1535.5
  2806.0,  1520.0
2.0,  1504.4
  2823.0,  1576.3
  2824.0,  1583.2
  2825.0,  2825.0,  1534.4
  2820.7
  2843.0,  1554.6
  2844.0,  1563.7
  2845.0,  1548.9
  2859.0,  1522.0
  2860.0,  1524.6
  2861.0,  1556.1
  2862.0,  1593.0
  2863.0,  1540.8
  2864.0,  2885.0,  1532.4
  2886.0,  1576.4
  2887.0,  1558.9
  2888.4.0,  1573.1
  2905.0,  1583.0
  2906.0,  1522.0
  2907.0,  17.3
  2921.0,  1547.6
  2922.0,  1513.4
  2923.0,  1546.4
  2924.0,  1571.1
  2925.0,  1505.9
  537.2
  2947.0,  1582.9
  2948.0,  1517.9
  2949.0,  1552.8
  2965.0,  1566.4
  2966.0,  1586.5
  2967.0,  1509.6
  2968.0,  2968.0,  1545.0
  2969.02989.0,  1528.7
  2990.0,  1506.1
  2991.0,  1572.2
  2992.0,  1511.0
  2993.0,  1517.9
  2994.0,  3015.0,  1560.8
  3016.0,  1526.5
  3017.0,  1582.2
  3018.0,,  1568.8
  3032.0,  1588.8
  3033.0,  3033.0,  1541.0
  3034.0,  1503.3
  3035.0,  1514.8
  3036  1533.6
  3058.0,  1589.0
  3059.0,  3059.0,  1586.4
  3060.0,  1582.9
  3061.0,  1585.2
  3062.0,  1546.6
  3063.0,  1  1509.4
  3089.0,  1500.0
  3090.0,  1567.8
  3091.0,  1515.6
  3092.0,  1570.8
2.0,  1555.7
  3113.0,  1594.1
  3114.0,  1552.1
  3115.0,  1523  3131.0,  1561.9
  3132.0,  1509.0
  3133.0,  1547.9
  3134.0,  1509.2
  3135.0, .0,  1587.8
  3154.0,  1588.4
  3155.0,  1563.3
  3156.0,  1562.9
  3157.0,  1556.9
 .0,  1596.4
  3178.0,  1598.8
  3179.0,  1543.2
  3180.0,  18
  3196.0,  1568.2
  3197.0,  1563.7
  3198.0,  1597.1
  3199.0,  1572.7
  3200.,  1571.2
  3219.0,  1561.9
  3220.0,  1534.3
  3221.0,  1505.9
  3222.0,  1575.7
,  3241.0,  1580.5
  3242.0,  1562.2
  3243.0,  1565.8
  3244.0,  1597.3
  3245.0,  15,  1597.4
  3266.0,  1537.5
  3267.0,  3267.0,  1527.2
  3268.0,  1519.9
  3269.0,  1559.9
  3270.0,  1520.2
  3271.0,  1520.1
  3298.0,  1568.8
  3299.0,  1557.2
  3300.0,  1584.0
0.0,  1537.6
  4361.0,  1591.2
  4362.0,  1566.8
  4363.0,  15541.1
  4377.0,  1510.8
  4378.0,  1583.5
  4379.0,  1551.7
  4380.0,  1533.0
  4381.0,  1590.7
531.8
  4403.0,  1568.1
  4404.0,  1518.9
  4405.0,  1550.2
  1553.7
  4423.0,  1571.1
  4424.0,  4424.0,  1596.9
  4428.0,  1525.7
  4439.0,  1532.8
  4440.0,  1537.2
  4441.0,  1526.3
  4442.0,  1598.8
  4443.0,  1589.3
  4444.0,  1568.9
4471.0,  1530.8
  4472.0,  1594.8
  4473.0,  1540.2
  4474.0,  1527.9
  4475.0,  1541.0
  4476.0,  4499.0,  1590.0
  4500.0,  1584.7
  4501.0,  1581.3
  4502.0,  4502.0,  1532.6
  450  4523.0,  1513.9
  4524.0,  1549.9
  4525.0,  1574.2
  4526.2.0,  1507.3
  4543.0,  1558.2
  4544.0,  1561.4
  4545.0,  1  4562.0,  1584.3
  4563.0,  1533.0
  4564.0,  1508.6
  4565.0,4580.0,  1549.3
  4581.0,  1513.8
  4582.0,  1501.8
  4583.0,  1546.8
  4584.0,  10,  1524.3
  4605.0,  1506.9
  4606.0,  4606.0,  1510.4
  46070,  1576.6
  4623.0,  1515.9
  4624.0,  1585.9
  4625.0,  1550.9
  4626.0,  1554.7
 ,  4645.0,  1593.0
  4646.0,  1544.7
  4647.0,  1506.6
  4648.0,  1559.9
  4649.0,  1,  1582.2
  4670.0,  1598.0
  4671.0,  4671.0,  1520.0
  4672.0,  1505.8
  4673.0,  1504.4
  4674  1540.5
  4696.0,  1526.2
  4697.0,  4697.0,  1549.5
  4698.0,  1570.9
  4699.0,  1522.6
  4700.
```

The HC-05 Module has Bluetooth 4.0 firmware, I found a link where there were some complaints about a buffer that was not present on previous firmware, I am wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction, the purpose of the system is to stream those two variables, and display them on an android device, the program for the device has not been started, I am attempting to get this data streamed correctly on the terminal first. I have also tried multiple terminal programs, and played with the settings on it.

I could also try another type of Bluetooth-serial converter, but would like to find the root of this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To me this looks like a performance issue. maybe you could [show us some of your source code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) that underlies the log data above. Btw. which Baudrate is used on the serial line?

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue, I am also having it.